# Python Pandas date groupby count calculate first instance of threshold

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

Having the transaction data for all customers for the last 10 years, I have a dataframe df:

```
   Customer_ID | date             | year             | Dollars 
    ABC           2017-02-07         2017               456
    ABC           2017-03-05         2017               167
    ABC           2017-07-13         2017               345        
    ABC           2017-05-15         2017               406
    ABC           2016-12-13         2016               320
    ABC           2016-01-03         2016               305
    ABC           2016-10-10         2016               456
    ABC           2016-05-10         2016               175        
    ABC           2015-04-07         2015               145
    BCD           2017-09-08         2017               155
    BCD           2016-10-22         2016               274
    BCD           2016-10-19         2016               255
```

I would like to add a flag, when a customer has their 4th visit in a year for the first time.

So this would be the output:

```
   Customer_ID | date             | year             | Dollars  | Flag
    ABC           2017-02-07         2017               456
    ABC           2017-03-05         2017               167
    ABC           2017-07-13         2017               345        
    ABC           2017-05-15         2017               406
    ABC           2016-12-13         2016               320         X
    ABC           2016-01-03         2016               305
    ABC           2016-10-10         2016               456         
    ABC           2016-05-10         2016               175        
    ABC           2015-04-07         2015               145
    BCD           2017-09-08         2017               155
    BCD           2016-10-22         2016               274
    BCD           2016-10-19         2016               255
```

I was going to do something this way, but it is not generating the output needed and I don't know how to flag the first time they have a 4th visit.

```
   df ['Flag'] = np.where(df[['Customer_ID']].groupby(['year']).agg(['count'])>3, 'X','0')
```

Comment: Is the example right ? I think the `X` should show up on `2016-12-13`

Comment: correct - thank you for catching it (the raw data went over the paragraph and I added the X in the wrong spot)

Comment: Fixed! so sorry

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you getting ``KeyError: 'year'``?

Comment: Yes, I am getting exactly that error - additionally even if it would work, it wouldn't flag only the first time they got to 4 visits, but each time they did in a year

Comment: I think my answer should works fine on you example data, if you have any question let me know .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then, You can try this ,I am using `cumcount`(Ps: you can drop the columns by `df.drop(['Count','Count2'],axis=1)`):

```
df['Count']=df.sort_values('date').groupby(['Customer_ID','year']).cumcount()
df['Count2']=df.sort_values('date').groupby(['Customer_ID','Count']).cumcount()
df['Flag']=np.where(((df['Count']==3) & (df['Count2']==0)),'X', ' ')


   Customer_ID       date  year  Dollars  Count  Count2 Flag
0          ABC 2017-02-07  2017      456      0       2     
1          ABC 2017-03-05  2017      167      1       1     
2          ABC 2017-07-13  2017      345      3       1     
3          ABC 2017-05-15  2017      406      2       1     
4          ABC 2016-12-13  2016      320      3       0    X
5          ABC 2016-01-03  2016      305      0       1     
6          ABC 2016-10-10  2016      456      2       0     
7          ABC 2016-05-10  2016      175      1       0     
8          ABC 2015-04-07  2015      145      0       0     
9          BCD 2017-09-08  2017      155      0       1     
10         BCD 2016-10-22  2016      274      1       0     
11         BCD 2016-10-19  2016      255      0       0
```

Comment: Glad it help, nice day

Comment: doesn't it have to be cumcount()+1 ?

Comment: In your case you do not need +1 , the first one cumcount will return 0. If you do need , you can add it , also for np.where change to df['count']==4

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go!

`df['Flag'] = np.where(df.groupby(['Customer_ID','year']).cumcount() + 1 == 4, 'X','')
df['Flag'] = np.where((df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Flag']).cumcount() == 0) & (df['Flag'] == 'X'), 'X','')`.

Edited for question misunderstanding, thanks @Wen. Here the last line drops duplicate `X`'s for a customer, so that only the first time a customer makes 4 purchases within a year gets marked.

When you do `df[['Customer_ID']]`, this creates a DataFrame object with *only* one column, named `Customer_ID`. Therefore when you try to extract a column named `year`, you get a `KeyError`, because that column doesn't exist. Another issue is that applying `groupby()` and then `agg()` returns a dataframe, which is not what you want.

Comment: It is not Op want

Comment: Thank you, but this would show me in each year, when a client reaches 4 visits; how can I flag only the first time?

Comment: Thank you very much - the explanation was very helpful

Comment: sorry, what are you referencing with "Finally, there's the issue of putting an 'X' only at the first time the 4th time is hit, and see above for details on that."

Comment: oh - you are referencing Wen's answer for some reason it dissapeared and re-appeared

Comment: Edited my answer and the code snippet should work as desired now. And yes, I went ahead and deleted the "Finally..." comment since it seemed to be confusing. Hope that helps and good luck! Thanks.